# WebSphere 6.1 - com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl Issue

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1

I am running an application in WebSphere 6.1.0.29 and am getting a com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found error.  Unfortunately the application isn't written by us so resolving this is proving to be a little difficult.

In another environment (6.1.0.27) we deleted the javax.xml.bind_2.1.1.jar and javax.xml.ws_2.1.1.jar from the application's library and that resolved the issue, but in this one we get NoClassDefFoundError on javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.

I read online that we could reference com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_6.1.0.jar in our Shared Library but then that prevents the application being accessible via the browser and instead shows a SRVE0255E error.

Any ideas?

Comment: SRVE0255E A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /abc has not been defined - means that you used wrong context-root or port combination, not that you have problem in application. Check context-root and verify how you are trying to access application.

Comment: @Gas, the error only occurs if I reference com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_6.1.0.jar in the Shared Library, so I doubt it is an issue with the context-root or port configuration.

Comment: Did you try to run with Parent last classloader setting for the application? You have some conflicting jars in the app. Add listing with jars you have in the app.

Comment: @Gas, yes I did but same symptoms as mentioned in the topic.  What do you mean by add listing?

Comment: List of jars that you have in WEB-INF/lib. As you have jars there which shouldn't be there. You should remove all xml and jax-ws related jars from there as WAS already provides Jax-ws implementation. Or you could try to disable provided runtime see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_6.1.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html?cp=SSAW57_6.1.0%2F1-7-9-4-1-14-0&lang=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gas was correct.  There were two Parent Class Loader settings in WAS, and setting them both to Parent First resolved the issue :)